# UIActivityIndicatorView appears blank

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am having this issue with my activity indicator in my cell. I start the animation in this method here then download the data from there I reload the table view and call stop animating when `numbersResponseData.length != 0` but I cannot see the activity indicator.

I have an accessory view arrow thingy that moves to the left when its loading I just cannot see the indicator.

This is inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{        
    if ((indexPath.row == 0) && (numbersResponseData.length == 0))
    {
        cellActivityIndicator =
            [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [cellActivityIndicator startAnimating];
        [cell setAccessoryView:cellActivityIndicator];

        // Call ASIHTTPRequest methods to start xml download/cache process
        [self setRequestString:@"Numbers.xml"];
    }
    //will set other cells up later
}
```

UPdate:

I added the UIActivityIndicator call inside  a different part of my if statement and now it applied the activity indicator to every cell but now I can see them.

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {        
            cellActivityIndicator =
                [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            [cellActivityIndicator startAnimating];
            [cell setAccessoryView:cellActivityIndicator];
        if ((indexPath.row == 0) && (numbersResponseData.length == 0))
        {
            cellActivityIndicator =
                [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            [cellActivityIndicator startAnimating];
            [cell setAccessoryView:cellActivityIndicator];

            // Call ASIHTTPRequest methods to start xml download/cache process
            [self setRequestString:@"Numbers.xml"];
        }
        //will set other cells up later
    }
```

I have debugged the .row if statement and its defiantly getting called.. I just don't understand why it would work from one if statement but not the next.

Comment: You will not see the indicator if you are using synchronous request since it's blocking the UI. Are you using synchronous request?

Comment: no I am defiantly using Asynchronous just checked it... it weird because the cell accessory view moves to the left then back to the right once its finished its just you cannot see the indicator at all.

Comment: I have fixed the issue and the code for initializing the UIActivityIndicator starting and stoping the animation is the same but  to get it to work correctly I had to change the if statement structure.. weird I know maybe its something else that caused it that I didnt click onto but from changing the if statements it seems to have fixed it properly.

Answer (score 1):

i think your UIActivityIndicatorView is hiding behind the UITableView. Dump this code and check do you able to see this indicator on view or not

```
    subViewActivityIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];
subViewActivityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(150, 220, 37, 37);
subViewActivityIndicator.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
[self.tableview addSubview:subViewActivityIndicator];
[subViewActivityIndicator startAnimating];
```

to remove use this,

```
    [subViewActivityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Okay I did this and no I cannot see the ActivityIndicatorView... :(

Comment: Check two things 1) You are adding subview right subview ([self.tableview addSubview:subViewActivityIndicator];) and 2) If you still have error you have to use selector afterDelay to call spinner method (    [self performSelector:@selector(getStartSpinner) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
)

Comment: I just tried something I have described it in the question above. Now I am thinking its an error with my if statement that this is called inside of.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this code from the UI loop, or from a worker thread?  You will need to use performSelectorOnMainThread: to invoke UI changes if you're calling from a worker thread.  Please refer to:

> http://blog.jayway.com/2010/03/30/performing-any-selector-on-the-main-thread/

Comment: I'm not really sure here as I am calling from inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: but calling a component of a tableviewcell so not sure if its the same as what is described above.